# The coefficients of a vector field in the Lie Algebra basis are smooth functions

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose $G$ is a Lie Group. $Lie(G)$ be its Lie Algebra. Let $\tilde{X_1},\tilde{X_2},\cdots\tilde{X_n}$ be a basis. Then in a local chart we can express every vector field $X$ as 
$$X= \varphi_1\tilde{X_1}+\varphi_2\tilde{X_2}+\cdots\varphi_n\tilde{X_n}$$
I do not understand why these functions $\varphi_i$'s are smooth.

Comment: I do not understand your question..

Comment: There is a basis for the Lie Algebra which comes from its isomorphism with the tangent space at identity.  Thats my basis. Now if $(U,x^i)$ is a local chart then for every $p\in U$ and for every vector field $X$ we can write, $X_p=\sum \varphi(p) (\tilde{X_i})_p$. These functions should be smooth. I don't see why.

Comment: When seeing $\textrm{Lie}(G)$ as the Lie algebra of left invariant vector field, the given decomposition is valid on the whole $G$ without working in a local chart. This is is a proof of $G$ being parallelizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's nothing to do with Lie group. Just write everything in local coordinates:

$$X = \sum_j a^j(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}, \ \ \widetilde X_i = B^j_i (x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}.$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = \sum_i C^i_j (x) \widetilde X_i,$$

where the matrix $C = (C^i_j)$ is the inverse of $B = (B_i^j)$. Since the inverse is given by determinant and cofactors, $C$ has smooth coefficients. Thus

$$X = \sum_j a^j (x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = \sum_{j,i} a^j (x) C^i_j(x) \widetilde X_i $$

and this implies $\varphi_i  = \sum_j a^j C_j^i$, which are smooth functions.